Why does \tikz add vertical space between textparts
I want to add a little logo at the right upper corner of a page. As recommended in some other threads, I want to use the tikz package.
But no matter, where I add my \tikz command, it adds some vertical space.
Could I avoid this? Or, if this is makes any sense, is there a workaround to get the same space, as if \tikz was not there?
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[portrait,left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%texlive-lang-german 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}


\begin{document}
    
text1\\
    
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[anchor=north east,xshift=-10mm,yshift=-10mm] at (current page.north east){\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-duck}};
    
text2 has more space to text1\\
    
text3 has normal space to text2\\

text4 has normal space to text3\\
    
\end{document}


Make the tikzpicture part of a paragraph.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[portrait,left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%texlive-lang-german 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north east,xshift=-10mm,yshift=-10mm] 
     at (current page.north east){\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}% >--- important %
text1
    
text2 has more space to text1
    
text3 has normal space to text2

text4 has normal space to text3
    
\end{document}

Don't use \\ to terminate lines.


That works so far, thank you.
But it looks a little different, if the first line on page is a \section{Section1}
Then there is space added above the section, whether I use \begin{tikzpicture} or \tikz.

@woelfchen42 You can put it in any paragraph on the page. In front of \section it wouldn't work, because \section starts a new paragraph anyway.
